# Check if tab is already open on mobile device?

Tags: javascript

I've got a button on my webpage that opens a new tab if my visitor is coming form a mobile device.

Code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|Android|IEMobile)/)) {
    window.open(the_URL);
}
```

How can I check if the visitor has already got an open tab from this link and take the visitor back to the open tab?

Meaning; I do not want to open a new tab every time the visitor clicks on this link.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

**Update**

I got this working in Safari (desktop)

```
var newWin;

    if(newWin) {
        try {
            newWin.focus();                 
        }catch(e) {
            newWin = window.open(the_URL);
        }
    } else {
        newWin = window.open(the_URL);              
    }
```

However its not switching to the other tab on iOS Safari..

**Update 2**

Tried to first close the window and then reopen it. However `.close` does not seem to work

```
    if(newWin) {
        setTimeout(newWin.close, 1000);
        try {
            newWin.close();
            newWin.focus();
        }catch(e) {
            newWin = window.open(the_URL);
        }
    } else {
        newWin = window.open(the_URL);              
    }
```

Comment: Good question, but i don't think you can.
Being able to query opened tabs from Javascript could mean a privacy/security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the window name property?

From MDN:

> **strWindowName**
>
> A string name for the new window. The name can be used
>   as the target of links and forms using the target attribute of an 
>   or  element. The name should not contain any whitespace
>   characters. Note that strWindowName does not specify the title of the
>   new window.

So modify your code as below

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|Android|IEMobile)/)) {
    window.open(the_URL, 'newWindowName');
}
```